# How to transform a dataframe of cluster/class/group labels into a pairwise dataframe of paired/unpaired?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, transform, transpose

I'm trying to find consistency among clustering results but I am trouble doing this efficiently.  I want to transform a `pandas` `DataFrame` object (or dict) of `i=node`, `j=iteration`, and `[i,j]=cluster/group`.  My current method is to iterate through all possibilities of this but I feel that there is a much more efficient way to do this.  This will take forever with large datasets.

```
import string
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import *

# Get alphabet as nodes
nodes = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

data = {0: {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 2, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 3, 'n': 0, 'o': 4, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 3, 's': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 4, 'w': 2, 'x': 2, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}, 1: {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 2, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 3, 'n': 0, 'o': 4, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 3, 's': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 4, 'w': 2, 'x': 2, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}, 2: {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 2, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 3, 'n': 0, 'o': 4, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 3, 's': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 4, 'w': 2, 'x': 2, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}, 3: {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 2, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 3, 'n': 0, 'o': 4, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 3, 's': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 4, 'w': 2, 'x': 2, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}, 4: {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 2, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 3, 'n': 0, 'o': 4, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 3, 's': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 4, 'w': 2, 'x': 2, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}, 5: {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 2, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 3, 'n': 0, 'o': 4, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 3, 's': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 4, 'w': 2, 'x': 2, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}, 6: {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 2, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 3, 'n': 0, 'o': 4, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 3, 's': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 4, 'w': 2, 'x': 2, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}, 7: {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 2, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 3, 'n': 0, 'o': 4, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 3, 's': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 4, 'w': 2, 'x': 2, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}, 8: {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 2, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 3, 'n': 0, 'o': 4, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 3, 's': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 4, 'w': 2, 'x': 2, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}, 9: {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 2, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 3, 'n': 0, 'o': 4, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 3, 's': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 4, 'w': 2, 'x': 2, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}} 
df_clusters = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

**How can I do this part more efficiently instead of bruteforce iteration? Is there a way to utilize `NumPy` arrays for this?**

```
# Get pairs of nodes and determine if they are in the same cluster/community/group
d_pair_iteration = defaultdict(dict)
for iteration, communities in df_clusters.T.iterrows():
    # Iterate pairwise
    for i in range(len(nodes)):
        # Node A
        node_a = nodes[i]
        for j in range(i+1, len(nodes)):
            # Node B
            node_b = nodes[j]
            # Determine if they are in the same community
            d_pair_iteration[frozenset([node_a, node_b])][iteration] = int(communities[node_a] == communities[node_b])

# Create dataframe
df_pairs = pd.DataFrame(d_pair_iteration).T
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy broadcasting, we can compare row `a` against the whole dataframe, then `b` against the whole dataframe, and so on:

```
# `x` is a table of 26 rows and 10 columns
x = df_clusters.values

# `y` is an array of 26 tables, each having 1 row and 10 columns
y = x[:, None]

# Using numpy broadcasting, `z` contains the result of comparing each
# table in `y` against `x`. So the shape of `z` is 26 x 26 x 10
z = x == y

# Reshaping `z` by merging the first two dimensions
data = z.reshape((z.shape[0] * z.shape[1], z.shape[2])).astype('int')

# idx is the 2-permutation of values in `df_clusters.index`:
# (a,a), (a,b), ..., (a,z), (b,a), (b,b), ...
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df_clusters.index, df_clusters.index], names=['node1', 'node2'])
result = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=df_clusters.columns)

# We don't want all permutations, only the unique combinations,
# so we have to slice the frame
from itertools import combinations
final_idx = list(combinations(df_clusters.index, 2))
result = result.loc[final_idx]
```

The result is a 325 x 10 datafraame, since C(26, 2) = 325. Here's a small sample:

```
             0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
node1 node2                              
a     b      1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
      c      1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
      d      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
      e      1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
      f      1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: I really need to learn how to broadcast better.  I would have never thought to reshape it in that way. Do you recommend any resources to learn broadcasting tricks like this better?  This sped up the bottle neck by 7x.